# MIPS assembly statement - solution unclear

Tags: assembly, mips

Reviewing some practice exam questions for class and one of the questions ask to write the assembly statements for a task...

Set the zero bit in the flag register

solution - add R1, R0, R0  ( there are many ways of doing it )

I'm not clear on why this would apply to the zero bit in the flag register?

Comment: The MIPS architecture does not have a Flag register.

Comment: I've never heard that MIPS has a flag before

Comment: the above instruction assigns 0 to $r1. Note that it should be `add $1, $0, $0`, `add $t1, $t0, $t0` or something like that

Comment: Perhaps the meaning of "flag" isn't what it seems? In an application, I might designate a particular register as a "flag" to indicate status to another process. So maybe the practice exam task includes "assign a register, in which we will set bits to use as flags", and then "Set the zero bit in the *flag register*". (Poor question, using the term "flag" which has a specific meaning in a microprocessor context.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Real MIPS processors (normally) do not have "flags".

However some universitary MIPS variants (I found some in Google) add flags for educational purposes.

Unlike MIPS CPUs nearly all other CPU types do not have conditional jump instructions that can jump dependent on a register value (like "BLTZ"). Instead they have conditional jump instructions that jump dependent on the result of the previous arithmethic operation.

Therefore these CPUs must have a special "register" saving information about the last result (like "result was negative"). This register contains special bits - the so-called "flags". One of these bits is the "Zero Flag" that indicates that the result was zero.

Note:

- The SPARC CPUs have an instruction set very similar to MIPS but they use a flag register instead of "BLTZ"-style relative jumps. So using such a CPU the original question would make sense even without adding non-standard registers.
- I would use "add **r0**, r0, r0" because this would not modify the r1 register.

Answer (score 0):

The `R0` register is hardwired to be the value zero, so adding it to itself will produce a zero result. Therefore the MIPS ALU will have its zero (Z) flag set.

Reference section 2.4.8.1 of the [MIPS32 Architecture For Programmers](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs3410/2014sp/MIPS_Vol1.pdf) document which states:

> Two of the CPU general-purpose registers have assigned functions:
>
> r0 is hard-wired to a value of zero, and can be used as the target register for any instruction whose result is to be
>   discarded. r0 can also be used as a source when a zero value is needed.